# Using SWT DateSpinner with RAP does not dispose calendar widget on focus lost

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rap

I am working on a project where I need to use the SWT DateSpinner on a RAP application webpage. I brought the entire Datespinner API into my project and have made changes to accommodate it in the application. I am trying to dispose the calendar widget when the user clicks anywhere on the page outside the bounds of the calendar dropdown.

To accomplish this I tried adding a focus listener to the widget and the actual date spinner but the onFocusLost() method is never executed whenever the datespinner or the calendar composite lose focus. I also tried to add a mouse event listener where I try to dispose the widget if the mouse down event occurs outside the calendar composite bounds but that doesn't get executed either. The showCalendar() method is as shown:

```
private void showCalendar()
{
    if (calendarDropDown != null && !calendarDropDown.isDisposed())
    {
        calendarDropDown.dispose();
    }

    calendarDropDown = new DropDown(this);
    calendarDropDown.setUsingRelativeControlWidth(false);
    Composite composite = calendarDropDown.getDropDown();
    composite.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    composite.setData(calendarToggle);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = this.getDate();

    // get current date in the control
    if (date != null)
    {
        c.setTime(this.getDate());
    }

    CalendarComposite calendarWidget = new CalendarComposite(composite, c);
    calendarWidget.setNoneEnabled(this.allowNullDate);
    calendarWidget.setMinimumDate(dateToCalendar(getMinimum()));
    calendarWidget.setMaximumDate(dateToCalendar(getMaximum()));

    // background to match the calendar
    composite.setBackground(calendarWidget.getBackground());
    calendarDropDown.show(true, composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

    text.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent event)
        {
              dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent event)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    calendarWidget.addMainCalendarListener(new CalendarListenerAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void dateChanged(Calendar date)
        {
            doSetDate(date != null ? date.getTime() : null, false, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void popupClosed()
        {
            calendarDropDown.dispose();
        }
    });         
}
```

And the show method of the DropDown is

```
 if ((autoHide && !dropDownShell.isVisible())){            
        dropDownShell.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if (!isInside(e.x, e.y, dropDownShell.getDisplay().getBounds()))
                {
                    dispose();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Please let me know what I can do to make the CalendarWidget dispose on losing focus.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no widget named `DateSpinner` in SWT. Is it a third-party component? Can you provide a link? Rather than uploading your entire project as zip file, could you quote the relevant parts here?

Comment: I have edited the main question with the relevant parts of the code.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if the widget you focus is in another shell than the currently focused widget (your Text), you may not get a focusLost event because each shell can have it's own focused widget. What is actually happens is that the shell the Text is in gets deactivated, which you can be notified about using a ShellListener.